# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'record'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I checked my credentials and they are correct moreover, the access is given to the database and I made sure that such a database exists in my xampp phpmyadmin, but it is still showing this error.
Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your codes which help us to debug. What you use and how you use. Can not guess the answer.

Comment: Please add other info like your code, error logs.

Answer (score 0):

possible solution be:
-check your credentials;
-check your privillage.
-check  from what user you get connected
you can connect via mysql -u root -p